# WCF Client Catching SoapException from asmx webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx, faultexception, soapfault

I have a WCF service that calls an asmx web service.  That web service throws an enxception that looks like this:

```
        <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:  error
                         service.method()</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://WEBADDRESS</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <message>Invalid ID</message>
                <code>00</code>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
```

In c# I can catch it as a FaultException however it has no details property.  How can I get at the details of this Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this for a long time I found that off of the FaultException object you can create a MessageFault.  MessageFault has a property HasDetail that indicates if the detail object is present.  From there you can grab the Detail object as an XmlElement and get its value. The following catch block works well.

```
 catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException FaultEx)
  {
   //Gets the Detail Element in the
   string ErrorMessage;
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageFault mfault = FaultEx.CreateMessageFault();
   if (mfault.HasDetail)
     ErrorMessage = mfault.GetDetail<System.Xml.XmlElement>().InnerText;
  }
```

This yields "Invalid ID." from the sample fault in the question.

Answer (score -2):

use a try catch block around the call to the web service, and then catch the soap exception

```
catch (SoapException e)
{
    e.Detail
}
```

if you want to throw non-basic FaultExceptions, (ie ones that contain details) you will need to add this behavior to your web.config and attach it to your `service` by using the `behaviorConfiguration` attribute.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="YourServiceNameOrAnythingReallyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Then you would want to throw a `new FaultException<T>(T)` where T is the type of the object that contains the details. You can then catch it on the outside as `FaultException<T>` and view the details that way. T may be a complex type, if so, you must decorate that type with the `[DataContractAttribute]`

Comment: "In c# I can catch it as a FaultException however it has no details property."

Comment: are you calling an old time web service, or is your WCF calling another WCF? are you catching the exception in your WCF service, or are you catching it in the calling program.

Comment: Its all in the question I'm calling an asmx service I'm catching it in the wcf service

Comment: FaultExceptions don't have details, only FaultException<T>, and I don't think old webservices throw FaultException<T>, so your out of luck, and even if they did, they would need to be configured to do so. If you don't have access to the webservice, you are again out of luck. Instead catch it as a SoapException and use the details it provides.

Comment: SoapExceptions details has nothing useful. So your telling me that exceptions thrown from asmx services can not be inspected by the client in .Net

Comment: you can see the information yourself, you can get the message detail as `e.Message` or the code detail as `e.Code`, or you can use `e.Detail` to get the xml tree representing the detail.

If the above is all you are getting, I'm not sure what more you want out of it.

Comment: No thats the raw soap I can't get than within .Net thats my point. E.Message as something generic, e.Details is not available.

Comment: Dinging me when trying to help is poor form.

Comment: I dinged you because you weren't trying to help just trying to tell me how wrong I am and not really reading the question.  Telling somebody "your out of luck", especially when you are flat wrong is poor form. Telling me to try the things I already said I did is poor form.

Comment: Dinging me because your feelings are hurt and because your answer was poor and wrong is bad form.  You should delete your  answer because again it is flat wrong and misleading.